# How redirect .htaccess to www. version? (not working)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in `.htaccess`. It doesn't seem to work for some reason. Can anyone see why? It's in the root of my website.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#Limit redirects at once (stops server crash)
 RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10

#Redirect visitors to www. version of website
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.MYDOMAIN.COM/$1 [R=301]
```

Obviously, `mydomain.com` is my domain name. Thanks in advance to anyone who can spot any problems!

UPDATE:

This works no problems. But if I access `mydomain.com/link1/link2/` then it does not work.

The .htaccess for '/link2/' is:

```
#settings
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
#homepage
 DirectoryIndex index.php
```

And for '/link1/':

```
#/linkgenerator/ never used, but temp redirect for neatness
 Redirect 302 /fbwiki/linkgenerator/ /fbwiki/link-generator/

#Serve error pages
  ErrorDocument 400 /link1/error.php
  ErrorDocument 401 /link1/error.php
  ErrorDocument 403 /link1/error.php?status=403
  ErrorDocument 404 /link1/error.php?status=404
  ErrorDocument 500 /link1/error.php?status=500
```

Comment: Don't see any problem other than missing `L` flag. Are you sure this .htaccess is indeed enabled & working?

Comment: Do you have htaccess enabled in the Apache config? `AllowOverride All`

Comment: It deoesn't seem to be since it's not actually doing the redirect and if I go to mydomain.com then it stays as that whereas it should go to www.mydomain.com.

.htaccess also works for other redirects, but those are after this redirect. I'll go minimal and see if anything is causing a problem.

Comment: Update: Okay, it seems as though it is working, but it just does not work on one directory in particular. I will update question to include the .htaccess of that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working for sub directories because those sub-directories have their own rewrite rules and by default these rules are not inherited by lower level .htaccess from their parents.

To overcome this you have 2 options:

1. Append similar `www` forcing rules in your lower level .htaccess as well OR
2. Add this line on top of your lower level .htaccess files:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteOptions Inherit
   # remaining rules will be below this
   ```

**UPDATE:** Keep your www rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: If I do this, it ends up redirecting everything where there isn't www. to the root of my website, at `www.mydomain.com`. It's a good start, but not 100%. Thanks!

Comment: So if I go to `http://mydomain.me/f/#home` I get redirected to `http://www.mydomain.me/#home`.

Comment: Can `$1` be used instead of `%{REQUEST_URI}`?

Comment: No don't use `$1` since that will strip current directory. See updated rule and test it in a new browser.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much! That tip about the `$1` saved my life!

One quick question though, is the `NE` flag necessary do you think? It seems to work fine with and without.

Comment: NE is probably not needed but sometime when there are special characters in URI then NE can help.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll leave it out for now since I shouldn't be having special characters in the URL's. I've made a comment/note in my .htaccess though incase I ever get a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This config works for me

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Really not sure what is wrong... :/

Comment: try it in incognito window or another browser

Comment: `AllowOverride` in httpd.conf is set to `All`, right?